# Team $A$ with $6$ players wishes to have ping pong matches with team $B$

Tags: probability

Team $A$ with $6$ players wishes to have ping pong matches with team $B$ which consists of $7$ players. Calculate the number of different single matches that can be held.

my answer is $^7P_6= 5040$

is that right?

Comment: What is P? And how do you motivate your answer?

Comment: @LionelRicci: probably permutations so $\frac{7!}{(7-6)!}$.  I suspect this is much too high, even if every player from team A has to play every player from team B.

Answer (score 0):

For single matches... that would be just $7 \cdot 6 = 42$, pick one of $7$, then pick one of $6$ and since those are picked independently there will be multiplication between.

---

If you want double matches, then choose $2$ out of $6$, and $2$ out of $7$. This is done independently so multiply those two. That becomes

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}6\\2\end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}7\\2\end{array}\right) = \frac{6!}{2!4!} \cdot \frac{7!}{5!2!} = 15 \cdot 21 = 315$$